# Where is wfp.tmf for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ipsec

I'm trying to debug IPSec Main Mode / IKE issues using wfp tracing and/or debugging of the IKE IPSec service. I've got the ETL files and tracefmt from the DDK, but I don't have wfp.tmf for my platform so the formatted event output is just a bunch of "No Format Information found".

Server 2008 R2 doesn't have wfp.tmf in %windir%\system32. Why isn't available and where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the Windows 2008 R2 wfp.tmf file is available for distribution. My understanding is that Microsoft has reserved it for internal use only. I would suggest calling PSS and see if they will share it you.